# multiple names in input fields

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a text field that posts to Mysql. It works fine.
What I want to do is have the same field do another function using javascript. It appears thats its one or the other. Not both. Any help would be nice.

This posts to MySQL (adminpassword = Mysql Field):

```
<input type="password" name="adminpassword" id="adminpassword" class="password" placeholder="e.g. secretpassword">
```

This Javascript function works, but not post to Mysql: (Obviously)

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="adminpassword" class="password" placeholder="e.g. secretpassword">
```

I have tried: (Javascript works, but does not post to MySQL)

```
<input type="password" name="password adminpassword" id="adminpassword" class="password" placeholder="e.g. secretpassword">
```

This is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#showHide").click(function() {
if ($(".password").attr("type") == "password") {
  $(".password").attr("type", "text");
    } else {
     $(".password").attr("type", "password");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are not clear .. what you want to do ?

Comment: your question is not clear and name="password adminpassword" , wrong

Comment: Changing it to ID (#) worked. Thanks. Post that again do that I can mark it correct?

Comment: your question is not clear please edit it to get correct answers

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden field and copy the value (before the submit) from the password input to the hidden input:

```
<input type="password" name="adminpassword" id="adminpassword" class="password" placeholder="e.g. secretpassword">
<input type="hidden" name="password" id="adminpassword">
```